# Volume of the set of two bodies

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

I have been given two bodys:

1. $(x^2+y^2) < R^2(x^2-y^2)$
2. $x^2+y^2+z^2 < R^2$

Now I am supposed to calculate the volume of the set of the two bodies.  I can see that the second body is a sphere, but I have no idea what the first body could be. Any ideas how to do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Should it implicitly be assumed that $z = 0$ for the first equation? Or is $z$ allowed to range over $\mathbb{R}$ for the first one?

Comment: I do not think so. (x,y,z) element of R^3 applies for both bodies.

Comment: points in the sphere which satisfies body 1.

Comment: I'm unable to figure out how to simply further (if you take the square root of both sides I believe there are 4 equations that come out, but I'm not sure) but for your first equation notice that
$$
(x^2+y^2) < R^2(x^2 - y^2) \implies (R^2 + 1)y^2 < (R^2-1)x^2 \implies y^2 < \frac{R^2-1}{R^2+1}x^2 
$$

Comment: Use spherical coordinates to do it.

Comment: So, clearly we need $R>1$. I would then recommend that you do the calculation in *cylindrical coordinates*, as the projection of the (half of the) region into the $xy$-plane is going to be the sector $|\theta|<\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{R^2-1}{R^2+1}}\right)$.

Comment: @8pir: You try that!! :)

Comment: It looks like a cheese cake slice at starbucks...